# Angular routing failing with request parameters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to route to a partial template on form submission in angular using `ng-view`. Along with the url, I am passing a parameter `?username=Joe`, which I hope to retrieve in the new partial using `$routeParams`.

Routing works if I do not pass any parameters : `$location.path('/submit');`
But the form button does not work if I pass parameters : `$location.path('/submit?userName=joe');`

Angular code:

**index.html:**

```
<body>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

**loginPartial.html:**

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**messagePartial.html:**

```
<p>Hello {{userName}}<p>
```

**angular code:**

```
angular.module('app',['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'loginPartial.html',
            controller:'LoginController'
        })
        .when('/submit',{
            templateUrl:'messagePartial.html',
            controller:'MessageController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo:'/'
        });

}])
.controller('LoginController',['$scope','$location',
function($scope,$location){
    $scope.submit=function(){
    $location.path('/submit');//routing works with no parameters passed
    //$location.path('/submit?userName=joe');//routing fails if parameters passed
    };
}])
.controller('MessageController',['$scope','$routeParams',
function($scope,$routeParams){
    $scope.userName=$routeParams.userName;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$location.path('/submit').search({userName:'Joe'})`

Also if you find that `$routeParams` is not working try injecting `$route` and then in your controller use: `var _params = $route.current.params`